# Find objects based on multiple criteria 10k+ times a second

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures

I have ~10-15 categories `cat1`,`cat2` etc that are fixed enums, which change once maybe couple of weeks, so we can say they are constant.
For example `cat1` enum could have values like that:

```
cat1: [c1a,c1b,c1c,c1d,c1e]
```

I have objects (around 10 000 of them) like these:

```
id: 1, cat1: [c1a, c1b, c1c, c1d], cat2: [ c2a , c2d, c2z], cat3: [c3d] ...
id: 2, cat1: [c1b, c1d],           cat2: [ c2a , c2b],      cat3: [c3a, c3b, c3c] ... 
id: 3, cat1: [c1b, c1d, c1e],      cat2: [ c2a],            cat3: [c3a, c3d] ... 

...
id: n, cat1: [c1a, c1c, c1d],      cat2: [ c2e],            cat3: [c3a, c3b, c3c, c3d] ...
```

Now I have incoming request looking like these, with one value for every category:

```
cat1: c1b, cat2: c2a, cat3: c3d ...
```

I need to get all ids for objects that match that request, so all objects that include every cat value from that request. Request and objects always have the same number of categories.

To get better understanding of the problem, naive way of solving that in SQL would be something like

`SELECT id FROM objects WHERE 'c1b' IN cat1 AND 'c2a' IN cat2 AND 'c3d' IN cat3 ...`

Result for our example request and example objects would be: `id: [1,3]`

I've tried using sets for that, so I had set for every category-category_value for example `cat1-c1a`, `cat1-c1b`, `cat2-c2a` etc with ids of the objects as values in that set and then on request I would do intersection between sets matching values from the request but having 5 digits of requests/s this doesn't scale really well. Maybe I could trade more space for time or trade almost all the space for time and precompute a hashtable with all the possibilities to get O(1) but amount of space needed would be really high. I'm looking for any other viable solutions to this problem. Objects do not change often and new ones are not added very often too so we are only read heavy. Anyone have any idea or suggestions or solved similar problem? maybe some databases/key-value stores that would handle this use case well? Any white papers ?

Comment: For ```cat2: c2a```, is the response id 3, or 1,2,3?

Comment: Hey @AbhinavMathur all values (every category) from request need to match. In our example object with id 2 is not matched because our request have `cat3: c3d` and object with id 2 doesn't include `c3d`:  `cat3: [c3a, c3b, c3c]`. If that was unclear or you have any other questions let me know, thanks!

Comment: How many categories are there on an average per id? And how many values do they have?

Comment: Number of categories around 10-20, max number of values for category around 50, average number of values per category around 6.

Comment: How many ids are there, that's what I wanted to know

Comment: around 10 000 of objects/ids

Answer (score 0):

I store your ids in a Python list `ids`. `ids[id_num]` is a list of categories. `ids[id_num][cat_num]` is a set of integers instead of your letters within your enums but all that matters is they are distinct.
From that list of ids you can generate a reverse-mapping so that given a `(cat_num, enum_num)` pair you map to the set of all id_nums of ids that contain that enum_num in their cat_num'th category!

```
#%% create reverse map from (cat, val) pairs to sets of possible id's

cat_entry_2_ids = dict()
for id_num, this_ids_cats in enumerate(ids):
    for cat_num, cat_vals in enumerate(this_ids_cats):
        for val in cat_vals:
            cat_num_val = (cat_num, val)
            cat_entry_2_ids.setdefault(cat_num_val, set()).add(id_num)
```

The above mapping could be saved+reloaded until enums/id's change.

Given a particular request, here shown as a list of enum contained in that numbered category; then the mapping is used to return all ids that have the requested enum in each category.

```
def get_id(request):
    idset = cat_entry_2_ids[(0, request[0])].copy()
    for cat_num_req in enumerate(request):
        idset.intersection_update(cat_entry_2_ids.get(cat_num_req, set()))
        if not idset:
            break
    return sorted(idset)
```

Timings depend on 10 to 15 dict lookups and set intersections. In Python I get a speed of around 2_500 per second. Maybe a change of language and/or parallel lookup in the mapping (one thread for each of your 10-15 categories), might get you over that 10_000 lookups/second barrier?